# VBA find not working - matched items not in table

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am creating part of one tool, which merges two SAP exports into one.

I know how many account numbers might be in the export (not all of them every month) and I have it almost complete except for the find issue, when account number is not in dataset, but is found and data merged are from the last exported account number

```
Option Explicit
Public lcol, lrow As Long
Public tabulka As ListObject
Public ColLetA, ColLetB, kcol, ddcol, zcol, account(1 To 6), header(1 To 10) As String
Public pname, pnameSQA, ftype, wbname, strFolderName, strFolderExists, path, pathS, wbnames As String
Public pvtFld As PivotField
Public Range1, Cell1 As Range
Public quarter, q, yearfile, monthfile, y, m, mm, qp, mp, yp, fm, astrLinks, item, itemh As Variant
Public fdatum As Date
Public wb, wbp, wbco, wbs, wbSUM, wbd, wbps, wbpe As Workbook
Public ws, wsd, wsH, wsN, wsZ, wsO, wss As Worksheet
Public i, x, r, z, v As Integer

Private Sub prepaymentsSTP()

'list of relevant account numbers for STP
account(1) = "51100"
account(2) = "52100"
account(3) = "314100"
account(4) = "314200"
account(5) = "314300"
account(6) = "314400"

'list of relevant headers for STP
header(1) = "Priradenie"
header(2) = "È.dokladu"
header(3) = "PrÚs"
header(4) = "Dr.dokl."
header(5) = "Dát.dokl."
header(6) = "ÚK"
header(7) = "       Èiastka vo FM"
header(8) = "FMena"
header(9) = "Text"
header(10) = "Nák.doklad"

''open workbook, activate sheet
wbnames = "Prepayments STP"
'Workbooks.Open pathS & wbnames
Set wbps = Workbooks(wbnames)
Set wss = wbps.Sheets(wbnames)
wss.Activate

Set ws = wbps.Sheets("Prepayments")
'Set ws = Sheets.Add
'ws.Name = "Prepayments"

'add headers in row 1 of new sheet
    ws.Activate
    Range("A1").Value = "Úèet"
    Range("B1").Value = header(1)
    Range("C1").Value = header(2)
    Range("D1").Value = header(3)
    Range("E1").Value = header(4)
    Range("F1").Value = header(5)
    Range("G1").Value = header(6)
    Range("H1").Value = header(7)
    Range("I1").Value = header(8)
    Range("J1").Value = header(9)
    Range("K1").Value = header(10)

'go back to STP sheet
    wss.Activate
    Range("A1").Select

'loop through accounts and headers to copy data from SAP export to Prepayments sheet/wb
    For Each item In account
        
        wss.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        On Error Resume Next
        r = Columns("E:E").Find(What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
            Debug.Print r
            If r > 0 Then

'find header 1 to get count of data for account
                    Rows(r + 4 & ":" & r + 4).Find(What:=header(1)).Offset(2, 0).Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                i = Selection.Cells.Count
                    
'copy account number i times in new sheet in first column
                    ws.Activate
                lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    Range("A" & lrow + 1).Select
                    
                    For v = lrow + 1 To lrow + i
                        Range("A" & v).Value = item
                    Next v
                    
'declare last row for ws after submitting account number
                lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    
'find header in SAP sheet and copy dataset for searched header and account
                    wss.Activate
                    For Each itemh In header
                        On Error Resume Next
                    x = Rows(r + 4 & ":" & r + 4).Find(What:=itemh).Offset(2, 0).Column
                    z = Rows(r + 4 & ":" & r + 4).Find(What:=itemh).Offset(2, 0).Row
                        Range(Cells(z, x), Cells(z + i - 1, x)).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                    
                        ws.Activate
                    'lcol = Cells(lrow + 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'cannot use, as the first line of one column may be empty
                    x = Rows("1:1").Find(What:=itemh).Offset(2, 0).Column

                        Cells(lrow + 1, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                        
                        On Error GoTo 0
                       wss.Activate
                    Next itemh
            End If
        
    Next item

End Sub
```

Problematic part of the code is

```
For Each item In account
        
        wss.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        On Error Resume Next
        r = Columns("E:E").Find(What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
            Debug.Print r
            If r > 0 Then
```

r is found for account numbers 314300 and 314400 and both are on line 168 where is 314200 located, which are not in dataset, interestingly it is not found for account number 51100, which is not in dataset either, I suppose that this might be some scholar mistake, but I am blind and cannot see it. I tried different attributes for find, but nothing works, if I use ctr+f in data and try to find it manually, with no luck using different settings, such string is not here

It is string as formatting from SAP is general for these account numbers

debug.print output looks like:

> x  2  102  168  168  168  168

The x is for blank space (case for debug.print for 51100)

Comment: Note that `Public lcol, lrow As Long` will declare `lcol As Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Public lcol As Long, lrow As Long` otherwise it is `Variant` by default! Same applies to all your other variable declarations! • Also `Public i, x, r, z, v As Integer` those should be `Long` because row/columns are counted in `Long`.

Comment: Also don't use `Public`/global variables if you can declare them locally in your sub/procedure. This is a bad practice. Good practice is to declare the variable as local as possible and as close to it's first use as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. As for Public, I currently have 16 modules called from "master" one, common variables are public

Comment: Still a bad practice (unless you need to transfer a value from one procedure to another). You should declare them in each procedure (especially counters like `i`, `x`, `r` …) otherwise any procedure can change that value in any other procedure! That quickly becomes a real issue when you work with events or `DoEvents` in VBA! • You will spend the time that you save declaring them properly 10 times in searching for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in here

```
For Each item In account       
    wss.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    On Error Resume Next
    r = Columns("E:E").Find(What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
        Debug.Print r
        If r > 0 Then
```

is that in the loop `r` is not reset! So `On Error Resume Next` prevents the error and leaves `r` with the old value (from the previous iteration of the loop)!

Solution:  Initialize `r` for each iteration in the loop

```
For Each item In account       
    wss.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    r = 0 ' Initialize r for each iteration in the loop
    On Error Resume Next
    r = Columns("E:E").Find(What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
        Debug.Print r
        If r > 0 Then
```

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
Your code should not contain an `.Select` statements and you should specify a worksheet for **every** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` object. Otherwise it is not clear for Excel which worksheet you mean and it can fail.

Also read the manual of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) where it says:

> The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

You only specified the parameters `What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole` that means the other parametrs can be random (there is no default) to whatever the user used in the find/replace dialog before your code runs.
To make your code reliable you need to specify all of them.

Comment: great, I thought it will be some basic error :(

as for the link, thanks, will read and correct the code.